# Adding number of images on UIScrollView from nsdata

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have 1000 images in an array in the form of NSData.and I need to show them on scrollview when pushing a view controller.

Currently what I am doing is I am creating image from NSData and add them on scroll view. But it takes long time to push screen from previous screen.

```
UIImage* img = [UIImage imageWithData:[imageArray objectAtIndex:i]];
```

The array has NSData for 1000 images, so it takes two much time to get convert it to a uiimage. How can I reduce the time it takes?

Comment: if you save those images in cache(resource and save path names in array then you can reduce time and u also can get image from resource imageWithContainsOfFile)

Answer (score 2):

May I ask why you don not use a UITableView, it is much more efficient as you can easily recycle cells, and it does the layout for you. I recommend this, loading images on demand, or at least keeping thumbnails in memory and swapping them out for the full size ones. It is not feasible to keep 1000 images in memory if they are larger than a thumbnail.

Comment: actually my requirement is to show them on ipad in a scrollview and  user should able to see them by scrolling scrollview.i can't wait user to see the image. i am creating thumbnail after converting into UIImage. image is of size 1024*768 when i am converting into uiimage

Comment: A UITableView is a subclass of ScrollView. I suggest using a CGAffineViewTransformation to turn it on on its side. (And then using a reverse cgaffinetransformation to turn the image right way up inside the cell). I've done this in iPad apps to create a magazine, and its very convenient and efficient. When the cell is needed to be displayed it will call cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, see Apple's Photoscroller in the developer site:  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotoScroller/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [AQGridView](https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView). It is deriving from UIScrollView, but has cell-reusing like UITableView.